# Skip azure function event hub output

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

I am using azure functions with an output Binding to an Event hub. There are cases where I cannot process the incoming data and therefore I also want to skip the Event hub output trigger. The functions call will fail if I just do not return anything. How should i handle this case correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: are you using the return value version or IAsyncCollector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return binding for event hub output requires exactly one output per function call. If you want 0 to x events per function call, you'll need to use the IAsyncCollector output binding like @silent mentioned in his comment.

Comment: thanks for your response, I'm using the python api, is this also possible with python? Do you have a docu reference for that or a sample code?

Comment: If you only want to output one message, but conditionally, you can use the func.Out method as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289303/azure-functions-python-send-eventdata-messages-with-properties-to-event-hub-ou). (It gives the example but the question is different). This way you can decide if you want to output a message based on your parsing. If you want more than one output message in Python, you'll have to use the SDK directly.